# How correct protect NXP NTAG215 for read/write

Tags: nfc

i've an big trouble with my NTAG215 tags.

I use this PDF below for reffer:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

**COMMANDS**

[image: commands]

I send these raw commands:

**AUTH TAG** ( with default password )

```
nfc.transceive('1B FF FF FF FF')
```

**CHANGE DEFAULT PASSWORD**

```
nfc.transceive('A2 85 AA BB CC DD')
```

**SET PACK**

```
nfc.transceive('A2 86 EE FF 00 00')
```

**PROTECT ADDRESS *04* TO *81***

```
nfc.transceive('A2 83 04 00 00 04')
```

**ENABLE READ/WRITE PROTECTION**

```
nfc.transceive('A2 84 10 00 00 00')
```

After send these commands, i read my NTAG215, and confirm results, but...i can read all memory blocks without PWD ( 1B command ).

I need protect these memory blocks from read without correct password.

[image: Memory blocks]

Thanks for all help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine except for the last command.

```
ENABLE READ/WRITE PROTECTION
nfc.transceive('A2 84 10 00 00 00')
```

In order to enable the protection the command must be as follows:

```
nfc.transceive('A2 84 80 00 00 00')
```

Comment: Perfect, now works.

Comment: I need to protect my NTAG from bad password after ten incorrect attempts.

First i protected page 04 to 81:

RAW COMMAND: A2 83 04 00 00 04

After this i can enable the brute force protection:

RAW COMMAND: A2 84 82 00 00 00

HEX 82 = BIN 10000010 

PROT = 1
CFGLCK = 0
RFUI = 0
NFC_CNT_EN = 0
NFC_CNT_PWD_PROT = 0
AUTHLIM = 010 ( 10 attempts )
But after 3 incorrect attempts my NTAG215 seems dead.

I'm doing something incorrectly?

Thanks for help.

Comment: @rodrigo286 change AUTHLIM = 010 to AUTHLIM = 00A. That should work. (Hex A = 10)

Answer (score 0):

So once a "session" is authenticated it stays authenticated until the session ends.

So if you connect with no/default/existing password, you then have to remove the Tag from the RF field so that the session ends.

The next time the Tag enters RF fields it will need authenticating again with the new password.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it, reading from the cell phone or computer, it's always possible to completely read the memory. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

nfc.transceive('A2 84 80 00 00 00') after send this command now
how i can  disable  READ/WRITE PROTECTION